# How to read a single space from input in C without pressing enter?

Tags: c, input, char, whitespace

I want a program to continue not by enter, but by single space printing. Is this possible in C? This is what the task I'm doing requires. My code so far:

```
while(if_continue) {
    printf("Continue? ");
    char char_continue;
    scanf("%c", &char_continue);

    if (char_continue != ' ') { 
        if_continue = 0;
        break;
    }
```

But this is obviously not going to work because for input you require enter. All sources I've read include multiple spaces between words only or solutions for other languages, plus scanf char skips any whitespaces before the word you're entering, so this is not the option.

How can I implement it?

Comment: You'll need some platform specific calls to turn of line buffering, alternatively, use a platform specific call to read a `char` that doesn't do line buffering in the first place.

Comment: @TedLyngmo what do you mean? I'm using VSC, but it's not a problem for me to run the program from console. What platform are you talking about? Sorry I feel like a dummy.

Comment: Terminals/consoles are typically line-based. It's them that forces you to press the `Enter` key to actually send the input to your program. The operating system will have special functions to read input in an unbuffered way, or to tell the terminal to not do line-buffering.

Comment: There is no standard way in C to do what you want, so you will need to see what's available in your environment. In Windows, `_getch()` or `_getwch()` could come in handy.

Comment: There is no portable way to achieve this.  The questions in reference offer different ways for different operating system.  I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77713584/4593267) for POSIX systems such as linux and macOS.  It might work on Windows if you use a compatibility library such as cygwin, otherwise you would need to use system specific APIs.